# Facebook image pop up menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i had tried to search for the way to achieve the menu through google/youtube etc and still can't found a way to achieve this.

How can i achieve the pop up menu almost like this?  :-
[image]

any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's the native UIAlertController with a style of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: @Jota Thanks you very much for pointing out the correct direction. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code to get achieve this same. This is working with Swift 3 and XCode 8.

```
    let actionSheet: UIAlertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Title of the action sheet", message: "Message to display", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
        //Just dismiss the action sheet
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(cancelAction)

    //Create and add first option action
    let savePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Using Camera", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        // Write Save Method Here
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(savePictureAction)

    //Create and add a second option action
    let sendInMessenger: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Existing Photo", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        // Write your code to Send In Messenger Here
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(sendInMessanger)

    //Create and add a third option action
    let dontLikePhoto: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Existing Photo", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        // Write your code if you Don't like photo Here
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(dontLikePhoto)

    //Create and add a third option action
    let trunOnNotification: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose Existing Photo", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        // Write your code Turn on Notifications Here
    }
    actionSheet.addAction(trunOnNotification)

    //We need to provide a popover sourceView when using it on iPad
    actionSheet.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView

    //Present the AlertController
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Please note that this method is available from iOS 9.**